# Can i upload a AMPL file to Wolfram Alpha and let it solve it?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, wolframalpha, ampl

I have a AMPL code and i need an web-based solver that return me results in a JSON/XML format. Can i do this with Wolfram Alpha API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [NEOS Server](http://www.neos-server.org) has an XML-based API for accessing AMPL and various AMPL-interfaced solvers over the web. I don't know of any ready-made AMPL hook to Wolfram Alpha, however, though I would be happy to learn of one.

Comment: With AMPL can I see output results in XML/JSON? Or the only command that I can use is "display x"?